# Estimate the number of unique strings

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

The task is estimate (not count) unique strings. It's difficult, because we have a lot of strings and no more that 8 Mb memory.

So the error has to be no more that 5%.

First, I tried to make Bloom Filters. I chose C++. But string contain letters from Russian alphabet, what make task more difficult.

Also, in this task possible to use Python with numpy and pandas, but I don't know how to use it for this task.

Somebody know, how to use it? Maybe some statistics?

Comment: Seems like it'd be useful to know how many strings is "a lot" and how big they can be.  If your strategy involves some probability of error (due to hash collisions etc), your estimate should factor in that probability.  (I suppose the solution could also keep track of stats like that and be flexible enough to build its own estimate, but if you knew the general bounds ahead of time it might help with coming up with a good approach.)

Comment: 8 MB is not too much, you can do it direct with pandas.Series.nunique() method, to create this Series use pd.from_csv(...) or other function that fit your file format. If you want to scale your data for 100s of MB or have any other reason, you can have a look at HyperLogLog algorithm (and Count-distinct problem at all, maybe some other useful algorithms are invented). HLL is implemented in a pip package hyperloglog, if you wanna give it a try.